# Playing songs from iPod Library

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm trying to play couple of songs from iPod library. I can play one song using this code:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artist = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Poker Face" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

MPMediaQuery *myArtistQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[myArtistQuery addFilterPredicate:artist];

[musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:myArtistQuery];
[musicPlayer play];
```

It plays one songs "Poker Face", when I added to previous code

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artist1 = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"Born This Way" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]

[myArtistQuery addFilterPredicate:artist1];
```

It plays nothing. I have array of song titles, and I want to play them if they exists.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Here is solution. Playing two songs from iPod library of an artist

`MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artist = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"AC/DC" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
[everything addFilterPredicate:artist];
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items]; 

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]; 
    if ([songTitle isEqualToString:@"Highway to Hell"]) {
        NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);
        [array addObject:song];
    }
    if ([songTitle isEqualToString:@"Thunderstruck"]) {
        NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);
        [array addObject:song];
    }

}

MPMediaItemCollection *collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:array];
[musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
//    NSLog(@"%@", [[MPMediaQuery songsQuery].items );
[musicPlayer play];`